# Call activity Method in Runnable Class

Tags: java, android, class, runnable

In my `Android` project, I have the `Activity` Morseapp and a Runnable class flash_code.
Now I want to start the runnable by the activity to make a new Thread and flash the code.
But the `Runnable` needs the morse-code String and the **ledon()/ledoff()** Methods.
So i want to define root to call the String etc. with. But at this line, it crashes and tells me something about a `Handler` - but I have no handler.. Hot is it possible to get the String or a Method?

**flash_code**

```
public class flash_code implements Runnable{

    public void run() {

         Morseapp root = new Morseapp();
                 Code = root.Code;
                 [...]

     }
}
```

**Morseapp.start_flash()**

```
  public void start_flash() {
    if(!flash) {
        flash = true;
        EditText OutText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.out_text);
        Code = OutText.getText().toString();
        Code = translate(Code, 2);
        t_flash.start();
    } else {
        flash = false;
        t_flash.interrupt();

    }
  }
```

Comment: You're not using the activity right(you're instantiating a new activity in flash_code which you shouldn't do) and I assume that you interact with the UI thread from the background thread(which is something to not do also).

Comment: A **handler** is an Android class that allows you to call methods of an activity from within a Runnable ... so this what you want to achieve your goal. If Android is already so kind to tell you, what to use, go ahead and use it.